# apuntar root a un subdirectorio con .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

tengo la regla para redirigir todas las solicitudes a https y apuntar a `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !{"scheme":"https"}
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

el directorio raíz es `htdocs`, pero necesito cambiarlo para que apunte a `htdocs/public` porque algunos framework usan la carpeta `public` como diretorio raíz. el problema es que encontré este ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/$ /yourfile.php [L]
```

y no logro entender como adaptarlo/implementarlo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esta manera?
En el (directorio) raíz(htdocs) agregas un **.htacess** con siguiente contenido. Es que el primero paso es redirigir todo contenido a la carpeta public.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

En el directorio htdocs/public agregas un **.htacess** con siguiente. Contenido. Aquí lo que hace es Manejar encabezado de autorización y mantener index.php como entrada. Finalmente todo http a https

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Manejar encabezado de autorización
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirigir las barras inclinadas finales si no es una carpeta....
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Manejar controlador frontal...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: gracias déjame ver si me funciona.

Comment: puedes añadir una explicación que hace cada parte de tu código???